# Having Problems with Dijkstra java code

Tags: java, arraylist

Having problems with Dijkstra Algorithm,

Trying to get paths between two cities.

Here are my java classes...

The ConnectedVertices class is where the vertice array is...

I used an arraylist to generate connections between cities

```
package main;

public class Edges
{
    public String u;
    public String v;
    public String d;

    public Edges(String city1, String city2, String distance)
    {
        u = city1;
        v = city2;
        d = distance;
    }
    public Edges(int city1, int city2, int distance)
    {
        u = String.valueOf(city1);
        v = String.valueOf(city2);
        d = String.valueOf(distance);
    }
}
```

here is the vertices and the arraylist to represent the graph.

```
package main;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Collections;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils;

public class ConnectedVertices
{
   public String[] vertice = { "lagos", "ikeja", "Benin city", "Agbor", "Sagamu", "Ibadan",
                        "Iwo", "Osogbo", "Abuja", "Kafanchan", "Jos", "Bauchi", "Gombe",
                       "Biu", "N’djamena", "Dikwa", "Maiduguri", "Damaturu", "Potiskum", 
                       "Azare", "Dutse", "Wudil", "Kano", "Kusada", "Chafe", "Gusau",
                       "Talata-Mafara", "Kaduna", "Zaria", "Ikire", "Ondo", "Sapele", "Warri",
                       "Yenegoa", "Portharcourt", "Aba",  "Ikot-ekpene", "Oturkpo", "Makurdi",
                       "Idah", "Lokoja", "Abaji", "Umuahia", "Owerri", "Akwa", "Damboa", 
                       "Egbe-ejiba", "katsina", "Sokoto", "Ore", "Calabar", "Agbor", "Onitsha",
                       "Lafia", "Enugu"};

   //public ArrayList<Edges> edges = new ArrayList();
   ArrayList<Edges> edges = new ArrayList<Edges>();

   public ConnectedVertices()
   {
       AddEdges();
   }

   class Vertex implements Comparable<Vertex>
   {
       public final String name;
       //public Edge[] adjacencies;
       public double minDistance = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
       public Vertex previous;
       public Vertex(String argName) { name = argName; }
       public String toString() { return name; }
       public int compareTo(Vertex other)
       {
           return Double.compare(minDistance, other.minDistance);
       }

   }

   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void AddEdges()
   {
       edges.add(new Edges(0, 1, 46));
       edges.add(new Edges(1, 4, 55));
       edges.add(new Edges(1, 2, 304));
       edges.add(new Edges(2, 49, 107));
       edges.add(new Edges(2, 31, 63));
       edges.add(new Edges(2, 3, 70));
       edges.add(new Edges(3, 51, 79));
       edges.add(new Edges(4, 5, 84));
       edges.add(new Edges(5, 6, 46));
       edges.add(new Edges(5, 29, 31));
       edges.add(new Edges(6, 7, 48));
       edges.add(new Edges(7, 46, 154));
       edges.add(new Edges(8, 46, 388));
       edges.add(new Edges(8, 9, 171));
       edges.add(new Edges(8, 27, 187));
       edges.add(new Edges(9, 10, 110));
       edges.add(new Edges(10, 11, 130));
       edges.add(new Edges(10, 52, 206));
       edges.add(new Edges(11, 12, 157));
       edges.add(new Edges(12, 13, 126));
       edges.add(new Edges(13, 45, 101));
       edges.add(new Edges(14, 15, 177));
       edges.add(new Edges(15, 16, 142));
       edges.add(new Edges(16, 17, 133));
       edges.add(new Edges(17, 18, 99));
       edges.add(new Edges(18, 19, 148));
       edges.add(new Edges(19, 20, 106));
       edges.add(new Edges(20, 21, 77));
       edges.add(new Edges(21, 22, 38));
       edges.add(new Edges(22, 23, 112));
       edges.add(new Edges(22, 24, 245));
       edges.add(new Edges(23, 47, 94));
       edges.add(new Edges(24, 25, 41));
       edges.add(new Edges(25, 26, 95));
       edges.add(new Edges(26, 48, 111));
       edges.add(new Edges(27, 28, 80));
       edges.add(new Edges(27, 8, 185));
       edges.add(new Edges(27, 10, 217));
       edges.add(new Edges(28, 22, 157));
       edges.add(new Edges(29, 30, 109));
       edges.add(new Edges(30, 49, 96));
       edges.add(new Edges(31, 32, 40));
       edges.add(new Edges(32, 33, 137));
       edges.add(new Edges(33, 34, 116));
       edges.add(new Edges(34, 35, 61));
       edges.add(new Edges(35, 36, 41));
       edges.add(new Edges(36, 50, 109));
       edges.add(new Edges(36, 42, 50));
       edges.add(new Edges(37, 38, 109));
       edges.add(new Edges(37, 53, 156));
       edges.add(new Edges(38, 52, 101));
       edges.add(new Edges(39, 51, 142));
       edges.add(new Edges(39, 40, 122));
       edges.add(new Edges(40, 41, 88));
       edges.add(new Edges(41, 8, 113));
       edges.add(new Edges(42, 53, 126));
       edges.add(new Edges(43, 51, 42));
       edges.add(new Edges(43, 34, 106));
       edges.add(new Edges(44, 51, 46));
       edges.add(new Edges(44, 53, 129));
       edges.add(new Edges(45, 16, 88));
       System.out.println("Contents of all locations: " + edges.size());
   }

   public String Connected(String first, String second)
   {
       int p,a;
       for (int i = 1; i <= edges.size(); i++) {
           for (int j = 0; j < edges.size(); j++) {
            //this is as far i could go...
        }
       }


   }

}
```

Please need help...

Comment: Saying this - **Having problems with Dijkstra Algorithm** is not enough to know the problems you facing and what is not working in your code.Ask specific questions to get answers.

Comment: You did not describe you actual problem, see [mcve].

Comment: I'm trying to get connection between two cities that their connections does not already exist in the arraylist. in the connection function i was trying to get the connection form on point to the order.

Comment: @Tabytha Your approach already starts hard... Every city is just a number... I would advice a more OO approach... 
But about the algorithm. You start at one point (Lets say City 1) and want to go to a different city (Lets say City 45). For each City that is connected to City 1 you should register the distance, then do that for the connected cities, so that they have the distance from City 1. DO NOT VISIT NODES THAT ALREADY HAVE BEEN VISITED. At the end you should have the shortest distance. See Wiki for info: ttps://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm

Answer (score 1):

You need a little more explanation of the algorithm I think:

```
   int p,a;
   for (int i = 1; i <= edges.size(); i++) {
       for (int j = 0; j < edges.size(); j++) {
        //this is as far i could go...
    }
   }
```

First read the wiki page with example of code:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm

And then have a look at(it use a queue), I cannot copy the code, it has no license. Please follow the link,

https://github.com/iensen/Algorithms/blob/master/Graphs/Djikstra.java